# collection.find on an item in a subarray

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following Object Structure:

```
[
  { 
     name: "someThing"
     ,securities: [ {"id": "2241926"} ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to return all objects in the outer array, that has at least one child secuirty with an id that starts with a value.  I have tried a few things and keep running up short.  On the mongoo console, this query works:

```
db.caseSummary.find({"securities.id": /^224.*/i})
```

We are using ES6, so please apologies for the generator syntax:

```
const q = require("q");

const startsWith = function(term){
    return new RegExp('^' + term + '.*', 'i')
}

const find = function*(collection, criteria){
    const command = q.nbind(collection.find, collection),
        myCriteria = criteria || {},
        results = yield command(myCriteria),
        toArray = q.nbind(results.toArray, results) ;

    return yield toArray()
}

const searchBySecurity = function*(mongo, term) {
  const collection = mongo.collection("caseSummary"),
      criteria = {"securities.id": startsWith(term) };

  return yield find(collection, criteria);
}
```

so **searchBySecurity(this.mongo, '224')** It returns an empty array, it should return the same results as the mongo console.  I guess I am missing a pretty basic concept in *translating my search criteria or invoking the find* writing this in node from raw mongo console query.

Edit 1: to be clear I want to return all parent objects, which have subarrays that contain a value that starts with the term passed in...

Edit 2:

I changed the criteria to be:

```
  criteria = { "securities": {
      "$elemMatch": {
          "id": "901774109" //common.startsWith(term)
      }
    }
  };
```

Still the same results.

Edit 3:

Using nodejs - mongodb "version": "1.4.38"

---

Edit 4:

this ended up not being an issue

Comment: Just a couple notes: with regex patterns you don't need to specify the optional wildcard match (`.*`) for the end of string especially if you aren't using the match for anything; and you can avoid using the `startsWith(term)` call altogether by using the mongo `$regex` and `$options`: `{'securities.id': {$regex: '^' + term, $options: 'i'}}`.

Comment: I am cleaning up my SO activity today , and I was tempted to remove this question since it was a non-issue.  I am deciding to leave it as it received a couple of upvotes and must have been helpful/interesting to someone.